# Empty PO file when scanning ctp files

Tags: cakephp, translation, poedit

I'm trying to localize my `php` app that uses `.ctp` files for the views.

Here a sample of a file's content:

```
<h2><?php __('Menu');?></h2>
<table >
<tr >
    <td  style="text-align:left>
        <?php echo $html->link('Main Config','/admin/configs/index')?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

PS: this is not my code and I cannot change it - but I need to translate it!

I tried following threads using `POEdit` and tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656322/how-to-read-in-cakephp-ctp-files-with-poedit), which however seems to be on a previous version of `POEdit`...

So I created a new `po` file for `de-DE` in my root directory (standard encoddings, ...), opened the catalog's preferences and added `.` and one specific `/subdir/test.ctp` file containing above code) to my source paths, then added `_` and `__` to the additional keywords (as well as some others I found to contain some text such as `input` and `link`, for example).

Then, whether I use update, update from source, no string is found - it says "Translated 0 from 0 (0%)"...

What am I doing wrong here?

**NOTE:** this is on a windows 10 pc with only `POEdit` installed, I didn't install `php` nor `php-gettext` installed directly on my machine, but they're supposed to be embedded in `POEdit` from what I could read...

Comment: Which version of CakePHP are you using? How are you setting up the `locale` setting for your application? Have you used the `i18n shell` as [described here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/i18n-shell.html)? To me it looks like you are missing steps. The POEdit is just an intermediarry step in the process. Depending on your setup it may be the last one. So it will not work just by itself.

Answer (score -1):

`.ctp` extension is not recognized by GNU gettext's `xgettext` as a PHP extension — such files are skipped over. I *just* added special treatment for it to Poedit [a week ago](https://github.com/vslavik/poedit/commit/fd9c44513fbb18476db82a9491ea06fa6a2f7ca1), so it will be fine in Poedit ≥ 2.0.8.

Until then, you can add a custom extractor (using the same syntax as in Poedit 1, see the placeholder examples in the window where you enter it) for `*.ctp` files.

Comment: Could you please advise as to where I can find the windows release of the latest release (found 2.0.7 on your website) and, until then, where, in previous version, I can edit "extractors"? Thanks!!!

Comment: I just upgraded but the I'm absolutely not able to create a project to update from ctp sources... Did you post a tutorial somewhere, or can you provide a sample pot file I can modify?

Comment: @neggenbe Nothing special is needed for *.ctp handling in v2.0.8+. Just standard setup that Google has a gazillion tutorials for ("poedit tutorial"). If you're seeing some problems, see http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html